# Runaway MathKernel!

Tags: kernel

I was running a simulation and everything went south (my fault, stupid coding error). So I quit the kernel. Everything was running very slowly, as if it were doing some kind of large calculation. Eventually I quit Mathematica. Everything continued to run slowly. So I opened up the terminal to see what processes are running (I'm on Mac OS 10.6.8, Mathematica 9.01) and observed that there was a "Mathkernel" process, using about half (and sometimes more - 57.2% in the sceenshot) of my CPU. I tried the "Kill" command, and even "sudo Kill" but it didn't even blink. I tried logging out and back in, but it was still there. Finally, I restarted my computer, and it was gone. My question: is there a more elegant way of recovering from such a runaway process?

[image]

Comment: Use `kill -9 43391` to force kill it.  Could it be a leftover parallel kernel?

Comment: Some 'fun' reading [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64697/is-there-something-stronger-than-force-quit). I always used to think -9 was "the ultimate kill weapon", but I'm not sure it's actually like that...

Comment: That's great... kill -9 does the trick. (This is the second time it happened, and so I hadn't restarted yet. Now I don't need to). I stand humbled in my unix-ignorance. And thanks also cormullion -- interesting reading indeed.

Comment: this has happened to me a few times when I am using parallelization (just like Szabolcs mentioned). could this have been the case here too?

Comment: I wasn't doing parallelization on purpose. It was a classic error: I intended to call one of the image processing functions with a real number but instead called it with a symbol. It churned and churned, and only after several minutes did I notice that it was "overdue." Then I quit the kernel and relaunched -- and went about my way... only noticing later on that everything was slow.

Comment: On Linux one can do `pkill -9 MathKernel` or `pkill -9 WolframKernel` for newer versions.